# get magnitude of values of a matrix and sort them in a descend way MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to get the magnitude of each value in a matrix, so:

```
 0.2964    0.8765    0.3793
 0.6832   -0.4721    0.5571
-0.6674   -0.0941    0.7387
```

is transformed?

```
 0.2964    0.8765    0.3793
 0.6832    0.4721    0.5571
 0.6674    0.0941    0.7387
```

to sort the in a descend way, we do sort(A,'descend'), but as I have negative values I would like to have the magnitudes and then sort, can this be done in a single instruction??`(get magnitudes and sort them in descending order)`

so at the end we get

```
0.8765
0.7387
0.6832 
0.6674
0.5571
0.3793 
0.4721
0.2964
0.0941
```

Comment: Do you just want to sort the absolute values, or keep the signed numbers in the order of the absolute values, or something else?  Your description is not clear.  Also, do you want to sort the flattened matrix (converted to a vector), or the rows, or the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
>> a

a =

    0.2964    0.8765    0.3793
    0.6832   -0.4721    0.5571
   -0.6674   -0.0941    0.7387

>> temp=sort(abs(a(:)),'descend')

ans =

    0.8765
    0.7387
    0.6832
    0.6674
    0.5571
    0.4721
    0.3793
    0.2964
    0.0941
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `sort(abs(A(:)),'descend')`

Answer (score 3):

Use [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) and [ABS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/abs.html):

```
>> x = [0.2964 0.8765 0.3793;  0.6832 -0.4721 0.5571; -0.6674 -0.0941 0.7387]

x =

                    0.2964                    0.8765                    0.3793
                    0.6832                   -0.4721                    0.5571
                   -0.6674                   -0.0941                    0.7387

>> sort(abs(x(:)), 'descend')

ans =

                    0.8765
                    0.7387
                    0.6832
                    0.6674
                    0.5571
                    0.4721
                    0.3793
                    0.2964
                    0.0941
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [abs()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/abs.html) function.

Comment: @dark: No, vice versa.  You want to sort the absolute values, not find the abs of the sorted values!